# Binding to Style Target using RelativeSource in Setter.Value

Tags: wpf, binding, relativesource

I want to create a Trigger to be applied to all TextBox on Validation.HasError to show the Validation.Error in a custom ToolTip.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource XXX}, Path=(Validation.Error)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**What should I put in the XXX?**

My problem is that I don't really understand how RelativeSource works in this context and I can't get the correct code for binding to the TextBox.

I am guessing Self would refer to the TextBlock and FindAncestor x:Type TextBox will fail becuase it will traverse from TextBlock > StackPanel > Setter.Value > Setter > etc.. instead.

**How can I refer to the Style Target instead?**

Answer (score 2):

Since `ToolTip` is not part of the visual tree, it's a bit cumbersome to get the behavior you want.

You can use its [PlacementTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placementtarget.aspx) property to find the element it is attached to, and set its `DataContext` to that element. In your case that will be a `TextBox`.

Now you can bind directly to the `Validation.Errors` property, and it will find the validation errors on a given `TextBox`.

You can use the following code to get it working:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ToolTip x:Key="errorTooltip" 
             DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget,
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ToolTip>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource errorTooltip}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```